# Inner class Constructor is not showing required output

Tags: java

I expected to get innerclass value as 8 but code is showing it as "0", why the value is not assigned to inner class constructor

```
public class Testit {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    test obj = new test(9, 8);
    test.test2 obj2 = obj.new test2();
    obj2.show();
    // TODO code application logic here
}
}
```

---

```
class test {

private int a;
private test2 d;

public test() {
    a = 0;
}

public test(int aa, int b) {
    a = aa;
    d = new test2(b);
}

public class test2 {

    private int b;

    public test2() {
        b = 0;
    }

    public test2(int bb) {
        b = bb;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("Outer variable " + a + " Inner Variable " + b);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: *"why the value is not assigned to inner class constructor"* - Because you don't call the correct constructor? Have you tried to read your own code and thought about what it does?

Comment: `obj2 = obj.new test2();` + `public test2() { b = 0; }`, you don't see how it's `0`?

Comment: Note that I have never ever seen a use case, in 20 years of Java programming, where it was a good idea to instanciate an inner class from outside of the outer class that way.

Comment: i'm new to java,, just started

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in the main method itself

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test obj = new test(9, 8);
    test.test2 obj2 = obj.new test2();
    obj2.show();
    // TODO code application logic here }
```

"Obj" is a new instance of "test" class. But "obj2" is a new instance of test2 (even if you use the obj reference having this new instance).

If you want to retrieve the built value, add a getter for test.d attribute and then change "`test.test2 obj2 = obj.new test2();`" by "`test.test2 obj2 = obj.getD();`"

You should print :

```
Outer variable 9 Inner Variable 8
```